# Mustache.js external template (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, mustache

I'm writing a component without jQuery as a dependency, and I'm hoping to find a way to load an external Mustache.js template without jQuery. Using jQuery's `$.get` method [appears to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24139587/931934), but I'm trying to do this in vanilla JS.

I tried using an `XMLHttpRequest` and appending the template to the body, and *then* hydrating it with my JSON, but when my JS tries to put the JSON in the template, the template isn't there to be hydrated (`cannot read property innerHTML of null`). Here was my code (in CoffeeScript, `test.js` is the mustache template):

```
req2 = new XMLHttpRequest()
req2.onload = ->
  foo = document.getElementById('thatsmyjam')
  templ = document.createTextNode(this.responseText)
  foo.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', templ)
req2.open('GET', 'test.js', { async: false})
req2.responseType = 'document'
req2.send()
```

This adds the literal text `[object Text]` in the DOM instead of treating it as HTML, so it seems to be evaluating the string of HTML rather than rendering it as such.

There's probably a better way. I'm basically trying to combine my App (getting the JSON), mustache.js, and the template into one concatenated, minified file for distribution as a UI widget.

I also looked into something like [Hogan.js](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/) to precompile the template, but it felt complicated, and I'm not able to use Node in this project.

### Update

If I update the above CoffeeScript to this:

```
req2 = new XMLHttpRequest()
req2.onload = ->
  foo = document.getElementById('thatsmyjam')
  window.templ = document.createTextNode(this.responseText)
  foo.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', templ)
req2.open('GET', 'test.js', { async: false})
req2.send()
```

then it's treated as a string in the relevant part of my app that tries to render the template:

```
populateDom: =>
    self = @
    @request.addEventListener 'loadend', ->
      if @status is 200 && @response
        resp = self.responseAsJSON(@response)
        # here, window.templ is a string returned from the XMLHttpRequest above,
        # as opposed to an actual "template", so Mustache can't call render with it.
        rendered = Mustache.render(window.templ, resp)
        document.getElementById('thatsmyjam').innerHTML = rendered
        self.reformatDate(resp)
```

So Mustache treats the string differently than a template inside of a script tag. Is there a way to get Mustache to recognize that string as a legitimate template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to retrieve an external template using core JavaScript using an implementation inspired by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2522467/931934). The process is, essentially, create a new `div`, retrieve the template with an `XMLHttpRequest`, and fill the created `div`'s `innerHTML` with the template string. Here's the implementation in CoffeeScript:

```
class TemplateManager
  templateUrl: '/path/to/template.mustache'
  retrieveTemplate: ->
    req = new XMLHttpRequest()
    req.onload = ->
      div = document.createElement('div')
      div.innerHTML = this.responseText
      window.mustacheTemplate = div
    req.open('GET', @templateUrl, { async: false})
    req.send()
```

You can then call

```
rendered = Mustache.render(window.mustacheTemplate.innerHTML, resp)
document.getElementById('YOURDIV').innerHTML = rendered
```

to render the template with `resp`, your JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 2018 alternative using fetch to get both the data and the template in parallel:

```
// Get external data with fetch
const data = fetch('data.json').then(response => response.json());

// Get external template with fetch
const template = fetch('template.mst').then(response => response.text());

// wait for all the data to be received
Promise.all([data,template])
.then(response => {

    resolvedData = response[0];
    resolvedTemplate = response[1];

    // Cache the template for future uses
    Mustache.parse(resolvedTemplate);

    var output = Mustache.render(resolvedTemplate, resolvedData);

    // Write out the rendered template
     return document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = output;

}).catch(error => console.log('Unable to get all template data: ', error.message));
```